# Difference between Users and Guest Users on Azure B2B AD?

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

My company currently has a few App Services hosted on Azure and needs to assign access to these apps to a few resources from another company. I need to build a small C# MVC app to create these users on our Azure Active Directory (which I am almost finished with). Before continuing, I would first like to understand the basic differences between "Users" and "Guest Users" on Azure Active Directory. Can anyone please explain this to me?

Also, if it helps, these users will not in any way be doing any Azure Portal maintenance. They will simply be accessing two or so of our App Services.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

User means your user type is `Member`. You could check this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-user-properties#key-properties-of-the-azure-ad-b2b-collaboration-user).

> Member: This value indicates an employee of the host organization and
>   a user in the organization's payroll. For example, this user expects
>   to have access to internal-only sites. This user would not be
>   considered an external collaborator.
>
> Guest: This value indicates a user who isn't considered internal to
>   the company, such as an external collaborator, partner, customer, or
>   similar user. Such a user wouldn't be expected to receive a CEO's
>   internal memo, or receive company benefits, for example.

Note: The UserType has no relation to how the user signs in, the directory role of the user, and so on. This property simply indicates the user's relationship to the host organization and allows the organization to enforce policies that depend on this property.

> Also, if it helps, these users will not in any way be doing any Azure
>   Portal maintenance. They will simply be accessing two or so of our App
>   Services.

If my understanding is right, you could give roles only to your web app resource group. So, your users only could access this two web app. More information about this please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure).

Comment: You could change user type from `Guest` to `Member`.

Comment: Thank you, the linked document answered all of my remaining questions as well!

Comment: @Shuishengbao How to change guest to a member?

Comment: From AZ powershell: Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "798d0d81-fc2d-48a5-b57c-a185bba65319" | Set-AzureADUser -UserType member

Answer (score 5):

Another important difference is that Guest permissions can be more limited than Members.

[image: External user restriction settings]

The first setting (Guest user permissions are limited), if set to Yes, will not allow Guests to get lists of users in the directory, and they also can't become admins.

There is also a separate toggle for if Guests can invite users to the directory.

Comment: The ability to limit guest permissions / invites is crucial for this project - thank you, this helps a lot!